# Can someone explain this syntax error with my if loop? Java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

```
  if(check !=0){  
        if (wee[i]>wee[i+1])
        {
            System.out.println("False");
            check = 0;
        else()
            System.out.println("True!"); 
       }
    }
```

The Code snippet contains a nested if loop.  The second set keeps returning "else without if" and i don't understand why.   I've tried it with and without the parenthesis.

to be more clear:  Why is the compiler returning an "else" without "if" error.

Comment: That's simply not how you write an `if`/`else` statement. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change what you have to this:

```
if(check !=0){  
         if (wee[i]>wee[i+1])
        {
            System.out.println("False");
            check = 0;
       }
        else
       {
            System.out.println("True!"); 
       }

}
```

Comment: It works better if you also explain the error.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm always forgetting to close {}.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the closing paranthesis for the inner `if` statement.

Try:

```
if(check !=0)
{  
   if (wee[i]>wee[i+1])
   {
     System.out.println("False");
     check = 0;
   }
   else
   {
     System.out.println("True!"); 
   }
}
```

Or for fun:

```
System.out.println(wee[i] > wee[i+1] ? "False" : "True");
```